# Have all promoted teams from one season of the united German Bundesliga ever been relegated in the following season?

Tags: football, statistics, bundesliga

Have all the promoted teams in one season ever been relegated in the following season?

The most recent season when this "almost" happened was 2012/13, when two previously promoted teams got relegated. But in this season there was a third promoted team, which didn't get relegated.

Comment: By "united German Bundesliga", do you mean since the Bundesliga replaced Germany's regional leagues in 1963-64, or since the East German league was folded into it in 1991-92?

Comment: @F1Krazy The first one!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has happened four times, although on all but one occasion, only two teams had been promoted the previous season:

- [In 1966/67](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1966%E2%80%9367_Bundesliga), when Fortuna Düsseldorf and Rot-Weiss Essen were both immediately relegated. (Only two teams were promoted and relegated in those days.)
- [In 1978/79](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1978%E2%80%9379_Bundesliga), when Arminia Bielefeld, 1.FC Nürnberg, and SV Darmstadt 98 were all immediately relegated.
- [In 1982/83](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1982%E2%80%9383_Bundesliga), when FC Schalke 04 and Hertha BSC were both immediately relegated. Only two teams had been promoted in 1981-82, as Bayer Leverkusen had won a play-off and got to keep their place; Schalke ended up in the relegation play-off in 1982/83 but lost and were relegated along with Hertha and Karlsruhe.
- [In 1992/93](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1992%E2%80%9393_Bundesliga), when Bayer 05 Uerdingen and 1.FC Saarbrücken were both immediately relegated. The Bundesliga had temporarily expanded to 20 teams in 1991/92 to include two East German teams as part of the reunification; only two teams were promoted that year while four were relegated.

Honourable mention goes to 1986/87: of the two promoted clubs, Blau-Weiß 90 Berlin were relegated, while FC Homburg went into the play-off (but won and kept their place).

There have also been nine occasions in which 2/3 of the promoted clubs were relegated: 1975/76, 1977/78, 1985/86, 1991/92 (though as mentioned above, four teams were relegated that year), 1999/2000, 2003/04, 2005/06, 2007/08, and 2012/13.

Comment: What was the reason for these immediate relegations?

Comment: @SnackExchange There's generally a significant gap in quality between a country's first and second leagues. Some promoted teams are able to bridge that gap through clever recruitment and tactical nous, and some aren't.